# SQL - Merge two tables with one common field

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, iseries-navigator

I've searched and searched but can't quite find what I'm looking for.  I'm not totally inept when it comes to SQL but this is beyond me.

So I have two table with one common field.

Table - LName
Feild Name

Table - Descripion
Field Name
Field Add
Field Job

Now, table LName has just the one field and it is populated.

Table Description has data in all fields except the 'Name' field.

I need to put the data from Field 'Name' in table LName into Field 'Name' in table Description.

Either that or merge both tables into one table (File3) that has all the fields but no data.

Appreciate any help.
Barry

Update 2:
I was able to craete a logical file that does what I want but only returns 1 record.

The SQL:

```
CREATE VIEW MISBXG.TEST_VIEW ( D COLUMN SYSNAM CHAR (8 ) NOT NULL  
 SYSNAM , LT                                                       
 DIADEV ,                                                          
 DITOPG )                                                          
 AS                                                                
 SELECT ALLISERIES.SYSNAM, CMPALTDEV.DIADEV, CMPALTDEV.DITOPG FROM 
ITTOOLS.ALLISERIES ALLISERIES INNER JOIN MISBXG.CMPALTDEV CMPALTDEV
ON ALLISERIES.SYSNAM = CMPALTDEV.SYSNAM WHERE CMPALTDEV.DIADEV <   
ALLISERIES.SYSNAM ;                                                

LABEL ON COLUMN MISBXG.TEST_VIEW                                   
(SYSNAM IS 'System Name' ,                                        
 DIADEV IS 'Alternate           Device' ,                          
 DITOPG IS 'Pager    Name') ;
```

Output of Query

```
System Name      Alternate       Pager Name
CHEVY                            AS400 PRIM
```

So now I have to figure a way for this SQL statement to read through all 28 records.

Barry

Comment: What RDBMS you are using ? show some sample data and what you have tried so far ??

Comment: So it sounds like you want to use something like JOIN... ON structure (or maybe a natural join). But I have a question for you because what you are trying to do doesn't make much sense. How are you going to sync to field name from LName to the field add, field job from Description. I'm assuming you want these things to be corresponding. Some more input would help a lot here.

Comment: Not surprised you can't find that. Need to know which dbms, and presumably, the first name in lname is the first name you want in description?

Comment: Yeah, real helpful @Dan     To all others, I will be more specific with what I'm looking to do, thanks.

Comment: I don't *fully* understand, because it seems you've switched from `LName` and `Descripion` (sic) to `MYLIB1/ALLISERIES` and `MYLIB2/CMPALTDEV`. Also `CMPALTDEV` should be exactly the same *as what* except for the `DIADEV` field? From what I can piece together, my guess is that your two files have records in the same order based on *relative record number*, a concept not generally present at all in SQL. If so, your best bet is to use the `CPYF` command with `FMTOPT(*MAP)`.

Comment: @JohnY   LName was an example.  You can dismiss it.  The Data in each record of CMPALTDEV will be the same. The DIADEV field should be blank.  I've tried CPYF with the *MAP option but it doesn't work as expected or hoped.  I need record 1 in the ALLISERIES table to merge with record 1 in the CMPALTDEV table.  since both tables have a 'SYSNAM' field, I thought SQL would be able to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never really addressed what I was looking for in my comment, and now you've edited the question so my comment doesn't even really make sense.  (For what it's worth, my suggestion of `CPYF` was probably not a good idea, but my understanding of your situation was, and still is, quite lacking.)

Based on something you said in your earlier edit, I am wondering if all the records in `CMPALTDEV` are actually duplicates of each other (with enough copies to match the number of records in `ALLISERIES`).  If so, then the simplest thing to do is probably dispense with any attempt to join, and just plug in the values from `CMPALTDEV` by brute force.  For example, if blank and `'AS400 PRIM'` are effectively the constant values you are trying to associate with each of the `ALLISERIES.SYSNAM` values, then make an empty copy of `CMPALTDEV` (I'll call it `CMPALTDEV2`) and just hard-code the constant values as follows:

```
INSERT INTO CMPALTDEV2
  SELECT SYSNAM, '', 'AS400 PRIM' FROM ALLISERIES
```

On the other hand, if the values in `CMPALTDEV` vary, and what you *really* want to do is match by "relative record number", IBM does give you the `RRN` function to do so:

```
INSERT INTO CMPALTDEV2
  SELECT T1.SYSNAM, T2.DIADEV, T2.DITOPG
  FROM ALLISERIES T1                        
    JOIN CMPALTDEV T2 ON RRN(T1) = RRN(T2)
```

*Please note:* Using the relative record number is a pretty hackish way to do anything in SQL. It's full of potential pitfalls, and really goes against what SQL is meant to be.  Most implementations of SQL (for other databases) don't have anything analogous to `RRN`, and best practice is to avoid using it if you can help it, even on the IBM i.

Comment: Thanks @John, The 'Brute Force' method will not work because the DIADEV field may not be blank and that is what I need to know, and from which system. Your RRN suggestion works just fine. I will test it thoroughly with certain data in different records in the DIADEV field but it looks good. Hackish as it may be, I'll take it. What esle ame I gonna do? Sorry, I'm not able to give you a 'useful' vote. Thanks, Barry

Comment: And so the potential pitfalls rears its ugly head.  It's only returning the first 24 of the 28 records.

Comment: If records have been deleted, there will be "holes" in the relative record number sequence.  You need to confirm that there aren't holes, by reorganizing (use `RGZPFM`).

Comment: Yes @JOHN, I had checked that.  But as it turns out, I was concentrating so much on the CMPALTDEV files that I forgot the ALLISERIES file.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Without an index in common this makes this task seemingly impossible... So this example only works by implementing a index of id on each table and setting them in order of the the assigned indexes. Sorry if this is confusing...

```
UPDATE LNAME DESCRIPTION
INNER JOIN DESCRIPTION ON
   DESCRIPTION.id = LNAME.id 
SET DESCRIPTION.field_name  = LNAME.field_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS (SELECT ln.Name, d.Add, d.Job FROM LName ln, Description d);
```

BUT I don't know why you want to do this... I mean, you need a relation between LName table and Description table, like a common id or something...

What exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Description (FieldName) 
SELECT FieldName FROM LName
```

is what you're looking for.  This will put all of the FieldNames from the LName table into the Description table - you can then update the other fields.

Unless you're trying JOIN the two tables where Decription.FieldName is null and LName.FieldName isn't... which is just not possible.